# With TestCafe and Electron, is there a way to execute script after the last test but before the app has shutdown?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using `TestCafe` to test our Electron app and need a way to know when the last test in a fixture has been executed BUT before `TestCafe` shuts our app down.

The standard hooks *(fixture.after, fixture.afterEach)* won't work. In particular, fixture.after won't work as it is called **BETWEEN** test runs (the test app will have been shutdown) and I need my app to still be around.

If I can get the number of tests active for this test run in the fixture I can count the runs myself and then call my custom code on the last test. If there is another way to do this that would be appreciated as well.

Any insights appreciated,
m

Answer (score 3):

You can create a special 'teardown' fixture, place all necessary code into it, and pass it at the end of the test file list:

```
testcafe chrome tests/* teardown.js
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, If I understand how TestCafe works, it would run all the tests under * in a fixture(s) and then shutdown our Electron app. So my app would already have been shutdown when it gets to teardown.js.

Comment: Please refer to this page: [https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#file-pathglob-pattern](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#file-pathglob-pattern). The "file-or-glob ..." argument allows you to run tests from multiple files in a single run without closing the application between them.

Comment: Is there a problem specifying a test in the fixture with the "-t" commandline option? I don't think it runs the second file with the -t option though I suppose the test in my teardown.js would match what I am filtering with "-t"?

Comment: I think that is my problem. In my case, I need to specify a specific test filter with the "-t" option. If I use it, it applies to all test files passed in. If I need to pass in "Click" then TC will look for a test with the text "Click" in the teardown.js as well which would be difficult to make generic.

Comment: Good idea. You can also do this via a config file with an array of glob patterns. It seems to process the glob patterns in sequence, so placing the "teardown" pattern last seems to reliably control the order. 

Plus they just switched to allow configuration from a JS file, so you could write a function and force the order files are passed to testcafe with that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [testcafe-once-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-once-hook) module which allows you to execute test actions once per fixture. Here is an example how to use it: https://github.com/AlexKamaev/testcafe-once-hook-example.